# Doing flutter firebase authentication server-side

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a flutter app with a firebase backend and I can't find any documentation for what I'm trying to do.  I am trying to have a user of my app (whose information is presumably stored in a FirebaseUser class) get their identity verified server-side and then if the identity is a certain user (verified by firebase serverless), they will be allowed to make a post to the db.  The firebase documentation has stuff for android, ios and web but not for cross-platform flutter development.  Can someone please point me in the right direction? I'm a little lost.  Thanks!

Comment: You're talking about server-side and about Flutter (which is a client-side app development framework). Which one is it? If you want to securely authenticate users, use Firebase Authentication in your Flutter code, as shown here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for helping out!  I want the server to create users and then send the data back to the app.  For authentication/verification, I want the flutter app to do an http request with the token and the server will verify and then run some code.  I was thinking of just following the web instructions?

Comment: What is this server that you're talking about? Where is it storing the user data? To use Firebase Authentication in your Flutter app, you usually just use the plugin I linked earlier in your app, without needing your own server.

Comment: Hi @frank can puffelen, I am using firestore and cloud functions. What if I want to do additional actions when an account is created, like create a database entry at the same time as a user is created?

Comment: You already tagged with Cloud Functions, which are the answer to that question. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

Comment: Ok, thanks @frank van puffelen!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Firebase with GCP will provide you this Server-Side authentication that you are asking for - so you don't need to worry. :)

If you just want to follow that, I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation from Firebase that talks about authentication. You can access this documentation in the below link.

- [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)

In case you indeed, need to use a private Server, I would recommend you to take a look at the below question that is already answered, about using a private server with Firebase. It should really help you achieve your goal.

- [Firebase authentication for private server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244311/firebase-authentication-for-private-server?rq=1)

Let me know if the information helped you!